# ubuntu/debian: using bluetile with GNOME2-like environment?

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop-environment, tiling-wm, mate-desktop

The installation of debian wheezy defaulted to the KDE desktop environment. How do I remove it and switch to GNOME 2 (the version that is used in stable)?

I fear that if I just install gnome-core, it will install GNOME 3. Can I just make sources.list point to an older version of some package?

I prefer GNOME 2 because it works well with bluetile <strike>(I don't want MATE, or other copies)</strike>.

Comment: Why don't you want MATE? It just picks up from where GNOME 2 left off.

Comment: I didn't think it would be able to work with bluetile. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed MATE and it looks just like GNOME 2. Bluetile runs fine as well, but it didn't start running upon logging in. Here's a [solution](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=872590) I found online:

> Adding these two files is one possible solution:
>
> /usr/share/xsessions/mate-bluetile-session.desktop
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Name=MATE + Bluetile
> Comment=Tiling window manager
> Exec=mate-bluetile-session
> Icon=bluetile.png
> Type=XSession
> ```
>
> /usr/bin/mate-bluetile-session
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> mateconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/caja/preferences/show_desktop False
> mateconftool-2 --type string \
>     --set /desktop/mate/session/required_components/windowmanager bluetile
> exec /usr/bin/mate-session
> ```

I'm not sure why the person I'm quoting decided to disable the desktop, mine is set to True. Make sure that /usr/bin/mate-bluetile-session is executable. You should then be able to select "MATE + Bluetile" from the options list when you login.

A second problem I've found is that the run application dialog doesn't come up with win-p. I installed gexec, mapped that to win+p, and changed the bluetile shortcut to Mod1+p.

Another solution: install grun and map that to win+p. Grun seems like the more traditional run application dialog box.

relevant:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57357/run-application-dialog-in-gnome2-alt-f2-without-gnome-panel
2. http://darkness.codefu.org/wordpress/2004/07/popping-up-the-gnome-run-application-dialog-from-a-script/